# On Kindle Fire 8, granting permission to Android apps

Tags: permissions, apk, google-apps, amazon-kindle-fire

This is a modified [cross-post from ebooks](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/8127/on-kindle-fire-8-granting-permission-to-android-apps), but perhaps more of an Android question since Kindle Fire runs on a bespoke Android build.

I have a Kindle Fire 8 (7th gen) running on Fire OS 5.3.6.4, which I believe is the same as 5.6.3.0, just misnamed. The [underlying Android build for this is Android 5.1.1 Lollipop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_OS).

I use RescueTime on my MacBook and Chromebook to log my on-screen activity, which has been tremendously useful. Unfortunately, while there is a native Amazon app for RescueTime, it is not compatible with any recent-generation Fire.

So I tried installing RescueTime on my Fire two different ways: First, [through an APK](https://apkpure.com/rescuetime-time-management-and-digital-wellness/com.rescuetime.android), and the through Google Play, which I use for common apps not available through Amazon like WordFeud.

To be useful, however, the app needs access to the Fire's app activity so I can track when I'm reading a book, the news, or, well, playing WordFeud. When I log in with either installation version, I get a generic android screen asking for permissions:

[image: IMG:]

I've got through the Fire's settings ad nauseam without luck. I see a "Device Administrators" option under "Security & Privacy," but when I open it I don't have any options to enable specific apps. All it offers is "Find My Device" and "Google Pay."

Is there any way, besides rooting the Fire and installing a native Android build, to allow apps to access the more generic Android-level permissions? I don't mind rooting the device -- it's out of warranty -- but would prefer not to switch the OS entirely. Thanks!